# In pypyodbc, How to query a table for its distinct values, truncate old table and append the distinct values to the empty table

Tags: python, pypyodbc

I have a table that for whatever reason has some dupes after a process runs.  Each row should be a distinct report.  I'm trying to do this with a for look on the cursor object after doing the .fetchall method and it is working somewhat.  But it only inserts one row.

```
import pypyodbc

conn_str = ('Driver={SQL Server};Server=*****************;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

con = pypyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT TDate, Report, Records, Status from Elig_Own.DST_Report_Status_Test")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
        TDate = row[0]  # first item in the tuple iterable
        Report = row[1] # Second
        Records = row[2] # third
        Status = row[3]  # fourth
        cur.execute("truncate table Elig_own.DST_Report_Status_Test")
        cur.execute('''INSERT into Elig_Own.DST_Report_Status_Test (TDate, Report, Records, Status) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''',(TDate, Report, Records, Status))      

con.commit()
con.close()
```

If I just print "row" within the for loop I get the list of tuples with all the fields and values I need for my table but I'm not sure how to pass these back into the empty table, all of the rows, not just one.  Why am I getting only one?

Answer (score 0):

You are truncating (emptying) the table each time you iterate through your `for` loop. Therefore, when the loop finishes, your table will only contain the last row you inserted. You probably want to execute the `TRUNCATE TABLE` just once, *before* you enter the loop.